# Customizing query string parameters in 'Submit' button in Phoenix HTML Form

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'd like to add some query string parameters to the request when a user hits 'submit' on an HTML form. Current template file code:

```
  <body>
  <h2>Create a new email subscription</h2>
  <p>This email address will recieve a message when a new order is placed.</p>
  <%= form_for @changeset, subscription_path(@conn, :create), fn f -> %>
    <label>
      Email Address: <%= email_input f, :email_address %>
    </label>

    <%= submit "Submit" %>
  <% end %>
</body>
```

It seems as though `submit` is meant to support some `opts`, however, they are undocumented.

https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#submit/2

Is there a way I can pass additional parameters to the request when the user hits 'submit'?

Comment: Do you want to pass the extra parameters always or only when the submit button is clicked (i.e. not when the user presses enter on an input field or submits the form using any other way)?

Comment: I need the parameters regardless of the way the user submits the form. Maybe I should use `hidden_input`

Comment: Yes, `hidden_input` is the way to go then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the code of `submit` at https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_html/blob/v2.8.0/lib/phoenix_html/form.ex#L533 under the hood it just pass the options to other function named `content_tag`

```
  def submit(_, opts \\ [])
  def submit(opts, [do: _] = block_option) do
    opts = Keyword.put_new(opts, :type, "submit")

    content_tag(:button, opts, block_option)
  end

  def submit(value, opts) do
    opts = Keyword.put_new(opts, :type, "submit")

    content_tag(:button, value, opts)
  end
```

If you look at the documentation for `content_tag` at
https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Tag.html#content_tag/2 you'll see some of the options you can pass:

> Creates an HTML tag with given name, content, and attributes.

```
iex> content_tag(:p, "Hello")
{:safe, [60, "p", "", 62, "Hello", 60, 47, "p", 62]}
iex> content_tag(:p, "<Hello>", class: "test")
{:safe, [60, "p", " class=\"test\"", 62, "&lt;Hello&gt;", 60, 47, "p", 62]}

iex> content_tag :p, class: "test" do
...>   "Hello"
...> end
{:safe, [60, "p", " class=\"test\"", 62, "Hello", 60, 47, "p", 62]}
```

If you need to send additional data to the server you can use a `hidden_input` https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#hidden_input/3